# Type or namespace could not be found - C# in Unity & VSCode

Tags: c#, reference, namespaces, .net-assembly, imagesharp

I am new to using C# assemblies. I am working on the C# script of an old project in Unity 2019.4.4f1 and I tried adding the SixLabors' ImageSharp assembly to the project but still get the *Type or namespace 'SixLabors' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)* error.

The script where the error arises from is located in the `ProjectName/Assets/SomeNestedFolders` folder and I made sure to include the following lines at the beginning of this script :

```
using SixLabors.ImageSharp;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Processing;
using SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Jpeg;
```

As this is a *legacy* project format there is no `.csproj` file to modify.
Is there a step to reference the assembly that I forgot or a file to modify further?

The ImageSharp version I used is the 2.1.4 one as it's the last one compatible with the .NET Framework 4.7.1. As I'm working on Linux and the project format is *legacy* (or *non-SDK*) I had to use Nuget CLI and a `packages.config` instead of the VSCode NuGet Package Manager to install ImageSharp into the `ProjectName/Packages` folder (where other assemblies where previously installed by coworkers before I arrived. Those coworkers are long gone though, and I have now way of contacting them...).

I've tried reimporting all assets inside Unity's `Packages` folder, and I don't find any "Add reference" button to add a `.dll` reference as found in other related questions.